# Styling auto generated HTML

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have following HTML output which i can not change. I want to specify the width and the text-align to right for the `label` text (ie. Name), but because i can not change the output, I am unable to do that. Is it still possible to do that without changing HTML?

```
<label>Name:<br><input type="text" value="" name="name"></label>
```

PS. I want to display label text and input field in same row, so I have set `float: left` for the `<br>`.

Comment: Are they in some kind of parent container? You could do `.parentcontainer label { text-align: left }` in your css.

Comment: You're floating a `br` element? That's a clever work-around. In my job I also have no control over the markup and am stuck 'hacking' with CSS.  By the way, it may be easier if you provided a little more markup, such as the parent elements and their CSS properties.

Comment: @KevinB thanks but as I said, I'd like to set the width for the label text as well, because there are multiple fields, so i'd like them to have same width.

Comment: @user1355300 So set the width of the input in the css too? how much of the code do you want us to write for you?

Comment: @user1355300 - [Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/kkgbV/5/) an example with multiple fields.

Comment: @KevinB take it easy, I didn't ask to write any code for me. I was just unable to figure out how to set the width of label text only, as it had the input field in it as well, but thanks to Mike Christensen for the nice example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just setting `BR` to `display: none;` should make everything appear on the same line.  You can set the text alignment on the `input` tag with `text-align: right` as well:

http://jsfiddle.net/kkgbV/1/

You can also make `label` a block element, and `input` float to the right:

http://jsfiddle.net/kkgbV/4/

Comment: Thanks, but i'd like to set the width as well like i said above.

Comment: So make `label` a block element, and make `input` float the right.

Comment: Or position the `input` absolutely.